API integration with Next.js giving error
The next.js is integrated with an API , the search is working with getting data , however 'details' on click to access further data , gives 404 error. I am using Edamam API. The browser url is
**http://localhost:3000/recipes/the-crispy-egg?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.edamam.com%2Fontologies%2Fedamam.owl%23recipe_db742742099859a8053b992dd3c1f452**

This gives 404 page not found.
/components/RecipeCard.tsx  , displays list of recipes on search
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { slugify } from '@/app/utils/slugify';
import { Box, Card, CardContent, CardMedia, Container, Grid, Typography } from '@mui/material';

interface RecipeCardProps {
  recipe: {
    uri: string;
    label: string;
    image: string;
    ingredientLines: string[];
  };
}

const RecipeCard: React.FC<RecipeCardProps> = ({ recipe }) => {
  const slug = slugify(recipe.label);

  return (
   
          <Card>
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              height="140"
              image={recipe.image}
              alt={recipe.label} 
            />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                {recipe.label}
              </Typography>
                   <Link href={`/recipes/${slug}?uri=${encodeURIComponent(recipe.uri)}`}  passHref>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="primary" component="a">
                  View Details
                </Typography>
              </Link>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>      
  );
};    
export default RecipeCard;

// pages/recipes/[slug].tsx  Suppose to display this page.
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Container, Typography, CircularProgress, Card, CardContent, CardMedia } from '@mui/material';

const APP_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID;
const APP_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_KEY;

interface RecipeDetailsProps {
  label: string;
  image: string;
  ingredientLines: string[];
  calories: number;
}

const RecipeDetail = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug } = router.query;
  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState<RecipeDetailsProps | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRecipe = async () => {
      if (!slug) return;

      const uri = decodeURIComponent(router.query.uri as string);
      const recipeId = uri.split('#recipe_')[1];
      
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2/${recipeId}`,
          {
            params: {
              type: 'public',
              app_id: APP_ID,
              app_key: APP_KEY,
            },
          }
        );
        setRecipe(response.data.recipe);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching recipe:', error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchRecipe();
  }, [slug]);

  if (loading) {
    return <CircularProgress />;
  }

  if (!recipe) {
    return <Typography variant="h6">Recipe not found</Typography>;
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Card>
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          height="140"
          image={recipe.image}
          alt={recipe.label}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
            {recipe.label}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            {recipe.ingredientLines.join(', ')}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Calories: {Math.round(recipe.calories)}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default RecipeDetail;

